# How to detect Gesture Recognition in front of Mobile Camera

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, gesture

So the problem statement is..

A person waves his hand in front of the camera then the App should automatically take a picture of him/her.

Can you help me find any libraries ? or how to achieve this ? Any Samples ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use image processing.
you can use opencv for android:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an Android library that does all of the image processing for you - it's called HandWave. Have you tried that option?

Comment: HandWave is no longer actively supported.